# What is a Javadoc summary fragment?

Tags: java, javadoc, errorprone

I am trying to adhere to [Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) as suggested by [Error Prone](https://errorprone.info/).

Section [7.2 The summary fragment](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s7.2-summary-fragment) states the following:

> Each Javadoc block begins with a brief summary fragment. This fragment is very important: it is the only part of the text that appears in certain contexts such as class and method indexes.

> This is a fragment—a noun phrase or verb phrase, not a complete sentence. It does not begin with A {@code Foo} is a..., or This method returns..., nor does it form a complete imperative sentence like Save the record.. However, the fragment is capitalized and punctuated as if it were a complete sentence.

Here is what I would like to know:

- What exactly is a **summary fragment**? It is stated that every Javadoc block begins with it and that it is text, but is there more documentation somewhere that I might read to get a better understanding about it?
- Why is the summary fragment **very important**? It is stated that it appears in class and method indexes, but I am not sure I understand what that means or why it is important. My best guess would be that it is a way to mark classes and it's members in such a way where it would be easier to search them.
- Where can I **find and read** the summary fragment? I am using IntelliJ IDEA, so I know how to access Javadoc for classes and members in code via inspection, but is there a way to list all available summary fragments?

Comment: Look at the "Method Summary" section [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html). It's the brief method description on the rightmost column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first two questions are answered [here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html#format):

- What exactly is a summary fragment?

> *The first sentence of each doc comment should be a summary sentence, containing a concise but complete description of the API item. This means the first sentence of each member, class, interface or package description*.

- Why is the summary fragment very important?

> *The Javadoc tool copies this first sentence to the appropriate member, class/interface or package summary. This makes it important to write crisp and informative initial sentences that can stand on their own*.

- Where can I find and read the summary fragment?

  - [Method Summary](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#method.summary) is a table, consisting of three (in some versions, combined in two) columns: "Modifier and Type", "Method", and a "Description". It briefly describes methods' functionality, i.e. - the API;<sub>*HashMap was chosen merely for the sake of demonstration example.*</sub>
  - [Index](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index-files/index-1.html) is a web page, indexing entire API of the particular Java build.

Both, "Method Summary" and "Index", are part of the Java doc.

Comment: Thanks for the information, this explains where the summary is being used - in the Javadoc summary sections to give readers clear and concise information. However, I am still interested in what method and class indexes are. The documentation you linked says that "Javadoc automatically places it in the method summary table (and index).", what does index refer?